# The command returns non-zero code in running docker file

Tags: angular, docker, dockerfile

I am running a docker file which is returning The command '/bin/sh -c node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod  --base-href $DEV_BASE_HREF --output-path=./dist' returned a non-zero code: 1

Below is the dockerfile:-

```
FROM node:12-alpine

ENV APP_ROOT /usr/src/webapp/
ENV DOC_ROOT /var/www/html/

ENV DEV_ENV development
ENV DEV_BASE_HREF https://apps-frontend-angular/

RUN mkdir -p $APP_ROOT $DOC_ROOT
RUN chmod 777 $DOC_ROOT

COPY . $APP_ROOT
WORKDIR $APP_ROOT

# RUN npm cache clean --force
# RUN npm install -g @angular/cli
# RUN set completion-ignore-case
# RUN npm install
# RUN ng build --prod


RUN chmod 777 init.sh

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install nginx -y
    
    

RUN npm cache clean --force \
    && npm rebuild node-sass \
    && npm install -g @angular/cli 

COPY default /etc/nginx/sites-available/

RUN npm cache clear --force && npm install --no-shrinkwrap --update-binary

RUN node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod  --base-href $DEV_BASE_HREF --output-path=./dist 


EXPOSE 80
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "init.sh"]
CMD ["dev"]
```

Basically the error occuring at the below RUN command:-
"RUN node --max_old_space_size=8192 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod  --base-href $DEV_BASE_HREF --output-path=./dist"

I am also getting below error in my Angular-application
"ERROR in src/app/modules/datamigration/builddmjob/builddmjob.component.html:3:3
- error NG8001: 'app-sidenav' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-sidenav' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'app-sidenav' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

```
        3   <app-sidenav></app-sidenav>
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        
          src/app/modules/datamigration/builddmjob/builddmjob.component.ts:5:16
            5   templateUrl: './builddmjob.component.html',
                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
            Error occurs in the template of component BuilddmjobComponent."
```

Not sure though the RUN command error is occuring due to code error or I have not written the command properly in my Dockerfile

Comment: The error message says it all - the Angular build is failing because it doesn’t recognize the `<app-sidenav>` component. Get your Angular app working correctly locally and then give the Docker build another shot.

Comment: The error resolved. I have deploy now Kubernetes pod, and it is running. how to access the application now? I have created deployment.yaml file for it